# p-confirmDialog not displaying properly

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Using p-confirmDialog I have few buttons that use this tool on one page..all are displaying fine except one where the confirmation  is triggered by a button on a popup, which the confirmation appears behind it and it is grayed out?

[image]

**HTML**

> Note: If I move my  p-confirmDialog inside p-dialog then it works
>   properly, however, other button like Delete won't get the popup

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="page-content">
            <p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle"></p-confirmDialog>

            <button type="text" (click)="confirmDelete()"  pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Delete"></button>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<p-dialog header="Request Info" [(visible)]="displayRequestInfo" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true" [width]="650" [minWidth]="300" [minY]="70" [baseZIndex]="10000">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Comment</label>
                <textarea name="txtcomments" [(ngModel)]="comments" cols="40" rows="3" style="width:98%"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <button type="text" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Post"></button>

        </div>
    </div>
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed t remove [baseZIndex]="10000" from p-dialog and
all worked fine